# how to disable status bar in android

Tags: android, securityexception

I am working on message app there i want to disable the status bar it should be shown but not touchable.

i have tried  below code:
In Activity:

StatusBarManager mStatusBarManager = (StatusBarManager) getSystemService(Context.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);

mStatusBarManager.disable(StatusBarManager.DISABLE_EXPAND);

In Manifest i have also added the permission :

But i am getting following error:

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: StatusBarManagerService: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.STATUS_BAR.

Comment: The docs for `android.permission.STATUS_BAR` say "Not for use by third-party applications."  Presumably that means you have to be root.

Comment: I am not using the third party application. I am customizing the default Android message app. and build as a system app

Comment: How are you building as a system app?  The error suggests that you only think you're building as a system app.

Comment: I am building the full source code and creating the system image and .fls file. using this command BUILD_FOR_KDUMP=yes make createfls -j32 and all the apk file stored inside the system/app and system/priv-app folder

Comment: Resolved! By adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in Manifest file and LOCAL_CERTIFICATE = platfform in Android.mk file.

Comment: You should put that in as an answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: And maybe change the title to "how to build as a system app", since the problem and solution aren't specifically related to the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! By adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in Manifest file and LOCAL_CERTIFICATE = platform in Android.mk file